# Document Management System with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, system, document, document-management

I want to find an application documents management system web-based. with PHP and MySQL.
I've tried alfresco, but it's based on java.

I want to find a document management application system using PHP & MySQL which has almost the same features with alfresco

I've tried xoda, php fusion and OpenDocMan but not appropriate.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try [DocMGR](http://www.docmgr.org/about/)  or [OpenDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com/). They could help.